# How to Get the package Names of System pre-installed applications in Android

Tags: android

I Already know how to get the package names of applications installed by the user.
But i cannot figure out how to get the package names of applications that are preinstalled or are system-ware like (Samsung Fit, Calender etc.) ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
    Log.d(TAG, "Launcher Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 
}
```

**ApplicationInfo** is having a **packageName** field which provides you package name of the application.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to get the list of system application `PackageInfo`,

```
public static ArrayList<PackageInfo> getSystemPackageInfos(final Activity context) {
    ArrayList<PackageInfo> list = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();
    ArrayList<String> packageNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    List<PackageInfo> pinfoList = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
    Collections.sort(pinfoList, PackageNameComparator);

    for (PackageInfo pinfo : pinfoList) {
        packageNames.add(pinfo.packageName);
        boolean isSystem = false;

        if (((pinfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0)) {
            isSystem = false;
        } else {
            isSystem = true;
        }

        if (pinfo.applicationInfo.sourceDir.startsWith("/data/app/") && isSystem) {
            //Non-system app
            isSystem = false;
        }

        if (!isSystem) {
            continue;
        }

        Bitmap icon = null;
        Drawable apkIcon = getApplicationIcon(pinfo.applicationInfo, context);
        try {
            icon = Bitmap.createBitmap(apkIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), apkIcon.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(icon);
            apkIcon.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            apkIcon.draw(canvas);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        }
        String name = pinfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();

        long apkSize = new File(pinfo.applicationInfo.sourceDir).length();


        list.add(pinfo);

    }
    return list;
}
```